# How to offer in frontend choice to pick one-time or monthly using Payment Element (donation flow)

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a donation flow. Where they can pick in frontend if want to donate once, or automatically monthly.

The flow for creating a one-time payment with Payment Element is:

- Create payment intent on server
- Frontend uses this to render Payment Element (payment element cannot render without payment intent)
- Frontend confirms the payment

Flow for creating a subscription with Payment Element is:

- Create subscription which has invoice payment_intent - I pass this to frontend
- Frontend uses this to render Payment Element
- Frontend confirms payment which starts subscription

My frontend offers option of "pay once" or "pay monthly". Is it possible to create a payment intent, and then attach this to subscription afterwards? Or the reverse, create a subscription, and then disassociate the payment intent from it if the user picks "once" in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to attach an existing non-Invoice PaymentIntent to a subscription.

What I would do is have a UI to select either "Pay once" or "Pay monthly" *before* you render the payment form, Based on what the customer picks, either create a one-time PaymentIntent, or create a Subscription, and then render the PaymentElement using the appropriate PaymentIntent from either flow.

Comment: Thanks, yah currently I was creating a subscription and plain payment intent before, so 2 api requests per page load, and use the different intent based on selection, but seemed excessive. Is it possible to disassociate the paymentintent of the sbuscription? to make it a non-subsciprtion plain intent in case the user chooses "once"?

Comment: Also the problem with creating subscription before hand is I need to know the customer. And a donation flow, I don't have a customer till after he fills out the form. And then I'm not able to update the customer on a subscription in case the user tried to re-use a saved customer id.

Comment: It's not possible to disassociate the PaymentIntent from the Subscription, and it's not possible to create a Subscription without a Customer object. Unfortunately overall I think you'll just have to adapt your flow to collect the information needed more upfront and do all the set up logic for "is it a subscription/one time payment" ; "is it a new or returning customer" before the point where you present the payment form with the PaymentElement in it.

Comment: Oh man. Thanks for your detailed replies.